# How to remove the hamburger menu icon in desktop screen but only needed in mobile device?

Tags: html, css, menu, navigation

Need help! This is a side sliding nav menu. I need to change this navbar showing without having hamburger menu icon (instead of menu icon i needed 'home,about'...etc) in desktop screen but only needed in mobile screen. Here is the code I'm using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
    transition: background-color .5s;
}

.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

#main {
    transition: margin-left .5s;
    padding: 16px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

<div id="main">
  <h2>Sidenav Push Example</h2>
  <p>Click on the element below to open the side navigation menu, and push this content to the right. Notice that we add a black see-through background-color to body when the sidenav is opened.</p>
  <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>
</div>

<script>
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks many help.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide a [mcve] to help people understand the problem we are trying to solve

Answer (score 1):

A media query with max-width tells the browser to apply the styles when the browser shrinks to that size. Min-width is the opposite. It tells to browser to apply the styles when the browser grows to that size.

In the second media query you listed, which is the first one that will activate when shrinking your browser, you're telling it to display: none which will hide the element and will remove the space it occupies. You're also setting visibility: hidden which will only hide the element but not remove the space it occupies. Using visibility here is redundant.

In the first media query, which is the second one that will activate when shrinking your browser, you're telling it to display: block which will undo the previous display: none, but you're still also setting the visibility: hidden, rather than switching it to visibility: visible, so the element still won't display.

Here's a simple example of a mobile-first approach, rather than desktop-first like your example, to show / hide a class.

```
.my-mobile-image {
   display: none; /* This is how it looks on mobile */
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
   .my-mobile-image {
     display: block; /* This is how it looks on desktop */
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the media query for show/hide based on screen width. Change the media query min-width to fix specific viewport(mobile screen width)

```css
.menu {display: none; /* Hide on Desktop */}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
   .menu {display: block; /* Show on Mobile */}
}
```

Preview at JS Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/itsselvam/r9uxtgaf/

Comment: It worked well in chrome developer tool when adjusting different device sizes. It is not working on  browser why?

Comment: @Sai, may I know how you are testing this code. Bcos for it works fine in both.

Comment: Updated the media query. Preview at https://jsfiddle.net/itsselvam/r9uxtgaf/. `@media (max-width: 600px)`. Change min-width to max-width.

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick tip!

If you are using bootstrap 4 you can use predefined classes to do this.

E.g. `<div class="d-none d-md-block">Hamburger Icon code</div>`

here the element has display none property for any screen that have a min-width less than 768px, and display block for min-width more than 768px.